# Multiple local Joomla websites using XAMPP

Tags: joomla-3.x

I installed XAMPP and Joomla! and everything works fine. Now I decided that it would be reasonable to have two local Joomla! websites to have more practice. How can I do that? It's pretty strange that there isn't much info on that. Where can I read about the way of creating one more Joomla! website using XAMPP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's relatively easy- you follow the same process as you do for installing a normal Joomla installation, but use a different subdirectory for each subsequent Joomla installation.

Example (updated)

- localhost/site1/
- localhost/site2/

It's also a good idea to use a different database for each one, but I guess you don't have to provided the database prefix is different for each site you create.

Comment: Typically this would mean that you either access the site at http://localhost/site1/ or that you set up hostnames locally for the different sites, which gets a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I don't like using `localhost/site1` and `localhost/site1`.

I prefer using a Virtual Host so everything is **completely** separated. The result would mean using domains such as:

```
site1.loc
site2.loc
```

Similar to:

```
site1.com
site2.com
```

It's a little bit of work to get set up, however the end result is far better.

We've compiled a few answer for different platforms which you can see below:

[Virtual host for Joomla](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4156/virtual-host-for-joomla/4157)

There is no answer specifically for Xampp, but one for Wampserver which I also prefer as it's more flexible in my opinion.

## Update:

#### Why is using a Virtual Host better?

- It results in a cleaner URL structure
- Setting up permissions for each individual domain is possible
- Dealing with base URL's can sometimes with an issue with some applications or CMS's **without** a Virtual Host
- You can use different ports for each Virtual Host (advanced usage)

There are probably some more technical advantages but that's something a server administrator would be able to shed more light on

Hope this helps

Comment: +1 For the great link, but can you elaborate more on why you think this method is better?

Comment: Cheers for that :)