# Change default url

Tags: url

I'm pretty new to Joomla! although I have coded in PHP. After installation (Bitnami), my default url is "https://localhost/joomla/" which is not cool. I want a new URL such as "https://localhost/chagbert/". How can I change this url?

Comment: Have you try this? https://bitnami.com/forums/forums/joomla/topics/directory-change

Comment: Please see how to set up a Virtual Host on your localhost: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4156/virtual-host-for-joomla which will look even "cooler"

Answer (score 1):

Ok, Thank you all for the input.

I discovered that the BITNAMI Xampp installation installs the Joomla! files in "C:\xampp\apps\joomla\" which i think is hard-coded in this particular Bitnami installation.

So I opted for a stand-alone stable installation of Joomla! And this was simply a copy and paste operation into a folder whose name would be my site name under the htdocs folder i.e. "c"\xampp\htdocs\chagbert\" where "chagbert" would be my site name. Thereafter, on the browser I simply had to call this address:

> https://localhost/chagbertos/

And the configuration process started.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Goto htdocs -> Here, you can change your default folder name joomla to chagbert.